# Asking user to provide data using for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, user-input

I'm running the below code:

```
list1 = []
no = int(input("enter your no. of subjects"))
for i in range(no):
    score = int(input("enter score for subject no ",i))
    list1.append(score)
print(list1)
```

My purpose of the piece of code is to ask user how many subject's score he/she wants to give and then take input score for each subject's score. But it's giving me the below error for line 4.

"TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given".

But I don't understand what are the 3 arguments. When I remove the i in line 4, it's working fine. But I want to keep track of score subject number wise. Can you please help?

Comment: you are passing the string "enter score for subject no " and the value of `i` to input as two seperate arguments. Input doesnt work like print where you can pass multiple args to be printed. I assume you meant to concat these like `score = int(input("enter score for subject no " + str(i)))` such that a stingle string is passed to "input" instaed of two individual parameters

Comment: what is the i doing in the input function?

Comment: or just use a nice clean `f-string` like `score = int(input(f"enter score for subject no {i}"))`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle..Thanks for the help. It's working fine. Can you please let me know why do we need to convert i to str?

Comment: @DerekEden - I need to ask user "Enter score for subject 1", like that. so I have put the i in the end.

Comment: the `+` can be used to concat 2 stirngs (I.E join them together). So this requires both left and right values of `+` to be strings. thats why you need to convert `i` from an int to a string. However I think its much cleaner to use the f-string way.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle, I'll use the f-string going forward. New learning for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = []
no = int(input("Enter number of subjects: "))
for i in range(no):
    list1.append(input("blah " + str(i)))

print(list1)
```

You can't write

```
input("text", i)
```

because then python interprets i as a parameter to pass to the input function, also just writing

```
input("text" + i)
```

isn't correct because python doesn't know how to add together a string and an integer, it isn't possible if you think about it in a literal sense.